# Why doesn't Bootstrap work during runtime when my page is loaded during runtime?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to use a carousel from Bootstrap Twitter.  The carousel works exactly like I want when I put the html directly in my .html file.  But I am trying to load the page dynamically.  When I load it, the display works fine, and only the active item is being displayed.  This makes me think that Bootstrap *is* working, but the items won't switch.

This file is working exactly like I want it to, but it is all in a single file, which is not what I want:

**index.html** ([Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qqb6wb90/))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Carousel</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
    <div class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'>
        <div class='carousel-inner' role='listbox'>
            <div class='item active'>
                <h1>First Horse</h1>
            </div>
            <div class='item'>
                <h1>Second Horse</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I try to load the contents from an external file, it doesn't work.  The initial display is still correct, but the carousel movement is no longer there.  So the use of bootstrap's col classes work, but Bootstrap's carousel does not.  Does anyone know why this is happening?  This is the broken code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Carousel</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<section id="test"></section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="load-carousel.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**load-carousel.js**

```
$('#test').load('carousel.html');
```

**carousel.html**

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'>
        <div class='carousel-inner' role='listbox'>
            <div class='item active'>
                <h1>First Horse</h1>
            </div>
            <div class='item'>
                <h1>Second Horse</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that `carousel.html` and the body of the working index.html are identical.

Does anyone know the cause of this?  Any ideas on how to load the page in the same way I am while having Bootstrap's carousel work?

Comment: my guess is the bootstrap scripts are fired before your content gets displayed

Comment: Check your browser's console for errors.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu any ideas on a fix?

Comment: If it's possible you could have your dynamic content contain the script so it fires it when loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap javascript that detects your carousel is executing before the html for the carousel is on the page.
You can manually initialize the carousel by

```
$('.carousel').carousel();
```

Comment: Any suggestions on where and how to invoke that?  I am not having success with it.

Comment: you can do something like this in your load-carousel.js: $('#test').load('carousel.html', function(){ $('.carousel').carousel(); }); so that the carousel function is invoked when the load is complete